Files freezes, exits since upgrade to 22.04.1 LTS
Does anyone know why Files seems to stop and exit/crash pretty regularly since I upgraded to 22.04.1 LTS?
Nothing else in my "environment" has changed. (I have always, however, tended to have up to 8 tabs open simultaneously ...)
Thanks! Baffled in GA ...
